# Copy to Clipboard in Android

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

I am not sure if this is possible, but what I need to do is take a file from app internal storage - I have a path to that file (it is .pdf file) copy it to clipboard so the user can go to let say 'my files' and paste that pdf file to some folder, or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the strings in clipboard and handle it as you wish in your own app .

Comment: But can I copy pdf file?